# How to add Firebase data to Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

[image]

I have a Firebase database, and I'm trying to add the data to an Array.

The problem, is that it's putting every value of the snapshot in the Array at index 0.

```
var id = snap.child("id").val();

var emptyArray = [];
emptyArray.push(id);
console.log(emptyArray[0]);
```

Result: 1 2 3 4 5 6

```
var emptyArray = [];
emptyArray.push(id);
console.table(emptyArray[1]);
```

Result: undefined

The loop I'm trying to use

```
for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
       emptyArray.push(id[i]);
   }
```

I've just tried making the id an array to work with the loop but still it's returning all data at index 0

```
var id = [snap.child("id").val()];
```

Full code for Firebase

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageNumber = document.getElementById("pageNumber").innerHTML;
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("data/p"+pageNumber+"/users/");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
   var id = [snap.child("id").val()];

   var emptyArray = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
       emptyArray.push(id[i]);
   }
    console.log(typeof emptyArray[0]);    
 })
});
```

Edit: I'm very new to JavaScript/HTML

Edit 2: Added a loop I just tried

Edit 3: Tried making the id an Array

Edit 4: Full code

Comment: What are you expecting to be in the array - what should the data look like?

Comment: @samdy1 ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"] - the IDs, but separated

Comment: can you add more code which is being used(loop)

Comment: @AkshayBande I wasn't at first, which is perhaps my downfall, but I've updated my question with a loop I just tried and it's returning 'undefined'

Comment: can you add value for `var id = snap.child("id").val();` ?

Comment: It will help if you explain what will be the value of `id`

Comment: @AkshayBande value of id is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 - probably should've used different numbers to not confuse, sorry. That's what they are in the database, but they are all being stored at the 0 index of the Array, rather than separated to different indexes

Comment: What do you get from `typeof emptyArray[0]`?

Comment: @samdy1 it returns number (I've also uploaded a photo of my database if that helps)

Comment: Could you post the code where you declare `snap`?

Comment: @samdy1 updated my code with the full function

Comment: Hopefully my answer will get the result you need. If that's not what you needed just drop in a comment and I'll change it to suit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what I think's happening is this event is calling on the `child_added` event so the snapshot `snap` is just the snapshot for one user.

Every time you get the result for one user you create the new array and just put in the ID for that user, then it goes out of scope at the end of the `on` callback.

Instead, you need to create the array outside the callback and just add to it, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageNumber = document.getElementById("pageNumber").innerHTML;
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("data/p"+pageNumber+"/users/");
var emptyArray = []; // Create the array outside the callback
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
   var id = snap.child("id").val();
   emptyArray.push(id); // Add the user's ID to the array
 });
console.log(emptyArray); // -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
});
```

Comment: No problem! Glad it helps